# Tkinter "entry" object not updating textvariable variable (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple Python program that will allow a user to input an IP address in decimal, or dotted-decimal format, then convert it to the opposite format and display it in the same entry box (ie, if they enter a decimal IP address, they can click a button and their input will be replaced with the dotted-decimal equivalent).

The problem I'm having is with pulling the data out of the entry box, then putting the new data back into the entry box.  I've written an example with just the GUI code, and none of my other conversion logic, to simplify the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")

win1 = tk.Frame(root)
win1.grid()

x = tk.StringVar()
y = tk.StringVar()

xBox = tk.Entry(win1)
xBox.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
xBox.textvariable = x

yBox = tk.Entry(win1)
yBox.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
yBox.textvariable = y

button = tk.Button(win1,text = "Calculate", command = lambda: copyVal())
button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

def copyVal():
    print("x: " + x.get())
    print("y: " + y.get())
    xVal = x.get()
    print("xval: " + xVal)
    y.set(xVal)
    root.update_idletasks()

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what I expect to happen with this code:

1. The value entered in the top box should be stored in `StringVar x`.
2. Clicking the "Calculate" button should run the `copyVal()` function:
3. `copyVal()` gets the value of `StringVar x` and stores it as `xVal`.
4. `copyVal()` sets the value of `StringVar y` to match `xVal`.
5. The text in the bottom box should now match the text in the top box.

Instead, it does not retrieve the value of `StringVar x`, so there's nothing to set `StringVar y` to.

I've tried the following variations:

1. Using `xVal = xBox.get()` instead of `xVal = x.get()`: this retrieves the contents of the top entry box, and sets the value of `StringVar y` to match it, but the bottom entry box does not change.
2. Using `command = copyVal()` instead of `command = lambda: copyVal()`: the `copyVal` function executes immediately upon program execution, rather than when the button is pressed.
3. Moving the `copyVal` function outside the root mainloop: raises a `NameError` exception when the button is pressed (`copyVal` is seen as not defined).
4. Moving `root.update_idletasks()` outside the `copyVal` function has no effect.

I've looked around for solutions to this issue, but no matter how many people I find who are experiencing similar problems, none of their fixes seem to resolve the issue for me (I usually see them told to use `StringVar()` to get/set values).  I am completely new to working with Tkinter, so I'm sure this is something really basic that I'm overlooking, and I appreciate any advice anyone can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python objects often allow you to add attributes to them arbitrarily:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.a = 1  # No error.  It makes a new attribute.
>>> foo.a
1
>>>
>>> def foo():
...     pass
...
>>> foo.a = 1  # Works with function objects too.
>>> foo.a
1
>>>
```

So, when you do:

```
xBox.textvariable = x
...
yBox.textvariable = y
```

you are not actually setting the `Entry`s' `textvariable` options to `x` and `y`.  Instead, you are creating new attributes named `textvariable` on each of those objects.

To fix the problem, either set each `Entry`'s `textvariable` option when you create the widgets:

```
xBox = tk.Entry(win1, textvariable=x)
...
yBox = tk.Entry(win1, textvariable=y)
```

or use the `.config` method to change them later:

```
xBox.config(textvariable=x)
...
yBox.config(textvariable=y)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something stupid I was overlooking.  It didn't occur to me that I'd done that incorrectly since it didn't throw an exception.